# Error (#8) An internal server error. Yii framework

Tags: frameworks, yii2, internal-server-error

I'm working on Yii2 project from external server. On that server everything work. But when I try to start it locally I get this error on first page.

```
Error (#8)
An internal server error occurred.
```

All other pages work except backend page. There I get the same error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: First of all you need to check error logs because this message is useless.

Comment: $Bizley, thank You for information I checked, but last error detected in error log has 01-Jan-2017 date.

Comment: @MikayelMargaryan check in {yourapp}/runtime/logs/app.log

Comment: @Yupik logs folder is empty :(

Comment: @MikayelMargaryan Check if directory have neccessary permissions to create log files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I changed value of YII_DEBUG to true

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```

in BaseYii.php file, got all errors and fixed them. Now everything works.

Comment: You should have looked for errors in `runtime/logs/app.log` or in web server (e.g. apache) logs to understand what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 5):

try this yii2 index.php

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
  if (@$_GET['debug'] == 1) {
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
  } else {
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The last few times I've gotten this, it's been overflowing memory.
update the limit in php.ini